# How do you get the "User Consent" in a WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

I refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

there is a paragraph stating that

> **Metrics**
>
> WebView may upload anonymous diagnostic data to Google when the **user
>   has consented**. This data helps Google improve WebView. Data is
>   collected on a per-app basis for each app which has instantiated a
>   WebView. An individual app can opt out of this feature by putting the
>   following tag in its manifest:
>
> ```
>   <meta-data android:name="android.webkit.WebView.MetricsOptOut"
>              android:value="true" />
> ```
>
> Data will only be uploaded for a given app if the **user has consented**
>   AND the app has not opted out.

The page does not have any further information about how to get user consent.

So the question now is, what is the code to activate this "User consent" in WebView? is this a settings on WebView like android's "permission" dialog box?

Comment: I'm exploring if there is a way to programmatically set this value in order to allow the user's the choice of opting in or not.

Comment: Being able to enable/disable the `meta-data` tag would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is talking about the global consent in the 'Collect App Usage Data' setting on the Apps & Games tab in the settings.

It doesn't pop up an extra box to get a special extra consent just for webviews.